# ElasticSearch - Script - Loop - Painless

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-painless

\I am not able to execute LOOP on subdocuments in Painless.
This is just one example scenario created to run LOOP the scenario is another (this case could be run filter but the problem is the loop in subdocuments).

```
GET /_stats

GET /product/_mapping
GET /product/_settings

GET /product/table/_search
{"size":99}
```

CREATEs

```
DELETE /product

PUT /product
{
"mappings":{
    "table":{
        "properties":{
            "name":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},
            "price":{"type":"float"},
            "subproduct":{
                "type":"nested",
                "properties":{
                    "category":{"type":"long"},
                    "subname":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},
                    "subprice":{"type":"float"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

DATAs

```
PUT /product/table/1
{"name":"Product 1",
    "price":123,
    "subproduct":[
        {"category":1,
            "subname":"SubProduct 1.1",
            "subprice":1.1},
        {"category":2,
            "subname":"SubProduct 1.2",
            "subprice":1.2},
        {"category":3,
            "subname":"SubProduct 1.2",
            "subprice":1.3}
    ]
}

PUT /product/table/2
{"name":"Product 2",
    "price":234,
    "subproduct":[
        {"category":1,
            "subname":"SubProduct 2.1",
            "subprice":2.1},
        {"category":2,
            "subname":"SubProduct 2.2",
            "subprice":2.2},
        {"category":3,
            "subname":"SubProduct 2.2",
            "subprice":2.3}
    ]
}

PUT /product/table/3
{"name":"Product 1",
    "price":345,
    "subproduct":[
        {"category":1,
            "subname":"SubProduct 3.1",
            "subprice":3.1},
        {"category":2,
            "subname":"SubProduct 3.2",
            "subprice":3.2},
        {"category":3,
            "subname":"SubProduct 3.2",
            "subprice":3.3}
    ]
}
```

QUERYs

```
GET /product/table/_search
{
    "_source":true,
    "size":9,
    "script_fields":{
        "sub":{
            "script":{
                "lang":"groovy",
                "inline":"price=0; for(s in _source.subproduct){if(s.category==2) price=s.subprice;}; return price;"
            }
        }
    }
}

GET /product/table/_search
{
    "_source":true,

    "size":9,
    "script_fields":{
        "sub":{
            "script":{
                "lang":"painless",
                "inline":"def price=0; for(s in _source.subproduct){if(s.category==2) price=s.subprice;} return price;"
            }
        }
    }
}

GET /product/table/_search
{
    "_source":true,
    "size":9,
    "script_fields":{
        "sub":{
            "script":{
                "lang":"painless",
                "inline":"def price=0; for(s in doc['subproduct']){if(s.category==2) price=s.subprice;} return price;"
            }
        }
    }
}

GET /product/table/_search
{
    "_source":true,
    "size":9,
    "script_fields":{
        "sub":{
            "script":{
                "lang":"painless",
                "inline":"def price=0; for (int i=0; i<doc['subproduct'].length; ++i){if(doc['subproduct'][i].category==2) price=doc['subproduct'][i].subprice;} return price;"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What do you want to get as result of your searches?

Comment: Resolvido ...

_source.field -> params["_source"].field